# execute sql command in python

Tags: python, sql, raspberry-pi

when i run this code in my raspberry-pi nothing happend and the code runs smouthly but there no results

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                 user="root", # your username
                  passwd="raspberry", # your password
                  db="raspberry") # name of the data base


cur = db.cursor() 


cur.execute("UPDATE visitors SET nb_visits = nb_visits+1 WHERE id = 1")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should [commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-commit.html) your transaction before changes take effect :

```
cur.execute("UPDATE visitors SET nb_visits = nb_visits+1 WHERE id = 1")
db.commit()
```